# Deployment diagram and hardware details

Tags: uml, modeling, diagram, deployment-diagram

Should deployment diagram contain such details as VPCs, firewalls, AWS zones and accounts boundaries, servers' count/CPU/cores, SaaS service tier/resources, names of the servers?

I'm modeling system in the cloud, so Deployment Diagram provides a small value over Component Diagram without at least some of those details. Google says Deployment Diagram [can contain hardware detail](https://creately.com/blog/diagrams/deployment-diagram-tutorial/#:%7E:text=A%20deployment%20diagram%20is%20a,and%20software%20of%20a%20system.). In the same time all examples (like [this](https://structurizr.com/share/1/diagrams#liveDeployment)) haven't got those information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I would say yes, if it is relevant for the future use of this diagram (e.g. colleagues should be aware of this info because a hardware migration might be due in the near future).

From the UML perspective, in my view, there is [no other diagram type](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html) which would be a better fit for holding that info. Btw, the diagram you've linked uses the [C4 deployment diagram](https://c4model.com/#DeploymentDiagram).